# How to run only specific worker in WorkManager Android (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

I have some script for workers and everytime I try to execute one specific worker, it executed all script workers I have instead.

this is how I run the script worker:

```
val stockTakingSync = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            UploadStockTakingSyncWorker::class.java,
            interval,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setConstraints(myConstraints)

    val stockTakingSyncWork = stockTakingSync.build()
    WorkManager.getInstance()?.enqueue(stockTakingSyncWork)
```

but this is return I got:

```
07-22 07:35:08.789 1327-1387/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump doSync: PrdPriceSyncWorker called
07-22 07:35:08.796 1327-1386/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump doSync: PrdSizeWorker called
07-22 07:35:08.803 1327-1388/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump doSync: PrdTypeSyncWorker called
07-22 07:35:10.120 1327-1404/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump doSync: PrdTypeSyncWorker called
07-22 07:35:10.123 1327-1386/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump doSync: PrdSizeWorker called
```

as you can see, all worker being executed it as well.

Answer (score 0):

after observing for a while it seems `WorkManager.getInstance()?.enqueue(stockTakingSyncWork)` also triggered **all 
 previous scheduled/queued tasks** that you already registered before.

it's not canceling/removing any `setPeriodicSync` just by pressing `RUN APP` or `DEBUG APP` even though you already remove all scripts to run WorkManager. **YOU HAVE TO UNINSTALLED the app to get rid of any previous QUEUED TASKS.**

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, and we fixed this as part of `alpha05`. This happens for only `PeriodicWorkRequest`s. For more info take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111195153

Comment: ah thanks for the Info. how about this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476480/workstatus-observer-always-in-enqueued-state ? bug or .. ?