# workstatus observer always in enqueued state

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

I am trying to observe my `workers` but they are always in `queued` state or sometime it's `RUNNING` but never `SUCCEED` or `FAILED`.

is `workStatus.state` from return in `doWork()` or it's different?

this is my worker script:

```
package com.mockie.daikokuten.sync.workers

import androidx.work.Worker


class TestWorker:Worker()
{

override fun doWork():Worker.Result
{
    return Worker.Result.SUCCESS
}

}
```

this is script to observe the workers :

```
 val test = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            TestWorker::class.java,
            PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addTag("test_worker")
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance()?.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("test_worker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, test)

    WorkManager.getInstance()!!.getStatusesByTag("test_worker")
            .observe(this, Observer { workStatus ->
                if (workStatus != null)
                {
                    for(ws in workStatus)
                    {
                        Log.d(":dump2 id ", ws.id.toString())
                        Log.d(":dump2 tag", ws.tags.toString())
                        Log.d(":dump2 state", ws.state.toString())
                    }
                }
            })
```

this is the result in Logcat:

```
 07-23 17:12:30.901 29740-29740/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump2 id: 5c6297f7-11d8-4f2f-a327-773672a7435c
 07-23 17:12:30.901 29740-29740/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump2 tag: [test_worker, com.mockie.daikokuten.sync.workers.TestWorker]
 07-23 17:12:30.901 29740-29740/com.mockie.daikokuten D/:dump2 state: ENQUEUED
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your periodic work request you should see

```
ENQUEUED - RUNNING - ENQUEUED
```

where the latter ENQUEUED is the state of the next work request.

You might get very briefly a SUCCEEDED between RUNNING and ENQUEUED, but I have never seen that.

For a onetime work request you see

```
ENQUEUED - RUNNING - SUCCEEDED
```

or whatever you return in doWork().

(Android 8.1 API 27, 1.0.0-alpha04)

Comment: does it mean I will never able to pass `data` from worker to UI when using periodic request? because it says `data` is set when `workstatus.state` is `SUCCEEDED`

Comment: The result of doWork() is primarily meant for the WorkManager. For instance, if you have a onetime request, where the worker returns RETRY, then the WorkManager enqueues another request despite of its onetimeness.

If you want to pass any data/information from the worker to the issuing activity, you would need to think of other mechanisms that can accomplish that.

Comment: this is what I meant https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker#setOutputData(androidx.work.Data). it says `This method is invoked after doWork() returns Worker.WorkerResult.SUCCESS and there are chained jobs available.`

Comment: OK, now I know what you mean with "data": passing a Data object from a (here periodic) workerA to a chained workerB. Again, the result of the first run of workerA might be briefly reflected in its state, but this state gets overwritten by the enqueued second run of workerA.

The fact that you do not see SUCCESS does not necessarily mean, that a Data object is not passed to workerB. This you should simply test. If it does not work, then it is a bug and should be reported.

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone who is having trouble getting their output data from periodic work.
It's more like a hack. 
In your Worker, just define a static mutable Live Data. 
At the place where you observe your work's state, observe this live data when your state turns to "RUNNING".

Here's a template :

1. The actual Worker:

```java
public class SomeWorker extends Worker{

   //This live data can be of any type. I'm setting Boolean
   Public static MutableLiveData<Boolean> outputObservable = new MutableLiveData();
   private boolean output_boolean;
   try{
       //Do you work here post your result to the live data
       output_boolean = SomeTaskThatReturnsABoolean();
       outputObservable.postValue(output_boolean);
       return Result.Success();
   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       outputObservable.postValue(!output_boolean);
       return Result.Failure();
    }
}
```

2. Your activity that observes this worker's info:

```java
//In YourActivity class inside OnCreate
mWorkManager.getWorkInfoForUniqueWorkLiveData(YOUR_TAG).observe (this,
   new Observer<List<WorkInfo>>(){
       @Override
       public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WorkInfo> workInfos) {
          if(workInfos!=null && (!(workInfos.isEmpty()))) {
             WorkInfo info = workInfos.get(0);
             switch(info.getState()){
               case ENQUEUED:
                   break;
               case RUNNING:
                   SomeWorker.outputObservable.observe(YourActivity.this,
                      new Observer<Boolean>(){
                      @Override
                       public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                           //EDIT: Remove the observer of the worker otherwise 
                           //before execution of your below code, the observation might switch
                           mWorkManager.getWorkInfoForUniqueWorkLiveData(YOUR_TAG).removeObservers(YourActivity.this);
                           if(aBoolean)
                             //Do whatever you have to if it's true
                           else
                             //Do whatever you have to if it's false
                           }
                      }
                   );
             }
          }
       }
   }
);
```

In this way you can observe your results when the state of the work is under running, before it gets switched back to enqueued.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. For PeriodicWork you should see:

`ENQUEUED -> RUNNING -> ENQUEUED`

However, there is a bug in `alpha04` which causes `PeriodicWork` to not run on API >= 23. This will be fixed in `alpha05`. For more info take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111195153.

IMPORTANT: As of a couple of days ago: `alpha05` has shipped. This bug is *fixed*.

Comment: my targetSdkVersion is 26. I am also facing trouble which `worker.doWork()` suddenly wont run anymore for some reason with periodicWork or OneTimeWork (it ran before) unless I uninstall the app. I even need to write another script with asynctask to make sure I did nothing wrong with my codes and it turned there was no problem with my codes using asyncTask. Thanks Rahul

Comment: one quick simple question. let say I have script `select * from bla bla` in `doWork()`, when that script executed ? in `ENQUEUED` state or in `RUNNING` state?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `PeriodicWorkRequest`s indeed never reach `SUCCEEDED` state, so you'll never be able to observe whatever value you return within your Result.success(yourData).

But all hope is not lost!
You can actually observe data in `PeriodicWorkRequest`s without any hacks like setting up static observables or writing/reading the data to/from shared prefs or a local database.

In doWork, we set data via setProgress, and add a non-blocking delay with Coroutine's delay() function before we return a Result:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        // do long running work, like waiting for the result of an async api call
        val outputData: Data = Data.Builder()
            .putString("asyncString", asyncString)
            .build()
        
        setProgress(outputData)
        delay(1000)
        Result.success()
    }
```

Then you can observe the LiveData (or Kotlin's Flow) retrieved by getWorkInfoByIdLiveData and read the the data you set in the Worker's setProgress with WorkInfo's getProgress():

```
val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .setInputData(workerData)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest)
val workInfo = WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.id).asFlow()

scope.launch {
    updateWorkInfo.collect { workInfo ->
        workInfo.progress.getString("asyncString", "")
    }
}
```

The 1 second delay we set in doWork() before we returned Result.success() is necessary because when Result.success() is called, the work immediately finishes and its state becomes `ENQUEUED`; you won't have enough time to observe any on-going work.

Read more:
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/observe