# How to avoid asynctask and WorkManager fetch same record of database

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-workmanager

I have two ways to sync between local database to server.

1. AsyncTask
2. WorkManager

Here is the flow of syncronization:

AsyncTask/WorkManager fetch data from local DB to upload to server --> `if (response.status == "success")` then remove the data

But the problem is, `AsyncTask` and `WorkManager` possible to run almost in the same time and fetching the exact same data each other that caused double data in server.

I need to use both since `WorkManager` is buggy and can't be trusted and I cant really rely on `Asynctask` alone as well.

Is there any way to avoid this double data?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to accomplish one task by one mechanism only - otherwise you will always run into concurrency issues.

What's *buggy* about `Workmanager? Maybe you have it set up incorrectly. There are good talks from the [Google IO in Workmanager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrKoBFLwTN0),
If you really encounter a bug, file an issue.

Furthermore there should be no need to use `AsyncTask` anymore, please try to avoid it completely as it really is very *error prone*. There are many better things for asynchrounous work (workmanager, coroutinen, rxjava, ...)

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476480/workstatus-observer-always-in-enqueued-state . take a look at rahul answer and I do facing the problem, sometime workmanager stopped to run (it was worked before)

Comment: `alpha05` has shipped, and the bug that you are referring has also been fixed.