# How to check PeriodicWorkRequest was completed?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Here's my observer (it's in the fragment)

```
workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(work.id)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { workInfo ->
                if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
                    //update UI
                }
            })
```

I need to update my UI on every PeriodicWorkRequest run. But it's state is always ENQUEUED according to documentation. `getRunAttemptCount()` gets reset between successful runs as well.

So, is there a way to check the completion of my work?

I thought it would be easier because in my Worker in `doWork()` I return `Result.success()` or `Result.failure()` and I even get a record about this in my terminal. Why I can't check for this in my code?

Comment: check the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76920949/9133569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, a PeriodicWorkRequest can never transition to `SUCCEEDED`. As soon as a job is done, the next execution is put into the queue. Thus, the state is always pending between `ENQUEUED` and `RUNNING`.

Here is a visualization from Pietro Maggi, one of Googles Developer Advocates. More easily digestable information on PeriodicWorkRequest can be found in his blog article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006

[image]