# observing PeriodicWorkRequest doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-notifications, worker

I'm wanna to use Worker for creating notifications for Jetpack Compose App.

this a function in TasksViewModel.kt

```
private fun setPeriodicNotification(context: Context, tasks: Flow<List<Task>>) {
    if (notificationGo.value) {
        Log.e("asd", "sadsad")
        createNotification(context, tasks)
    }
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

    val notificationWorker =
        PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag("TAG")
            .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, notificationWorker)

    workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(notificationWorker.id).observeForever(androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
        if(it.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED){
            Log.e("workinfo", "succeeded")
        }
    })

}
```

in the Logcat showing that Worker result - SUCCESS

```
Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=f44d3ebb-74cb-41c0-b1dd-ca25a7c50d94, tags={ com.example.goneappforandroid.NotificationWorker } ]
```

but after that the log.e is not printed

Comment: check the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76920949/9133569

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the minimum repeat interval that can be defined is 15 minutes.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest

And PeriodicWorkRequests never get SUCCEED state. It remains between ENQUEUED and RUNNING.
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/states#periodic_work_states

Just try to print the workInfo.getState outside the if, and you'll see what you are getting. Something like this:

```
.observeForever(workInfo -> {
                if (workInfo != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "WorkInfo received: state: " + workInfo.getState());
                }
            }
```